# Random numbers recived by wifi shield

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, http

So I am sending a web request to a server, but for some reason the result is the number: `728484804749464932504848327975131083101114118101114583213106897116101583284117101443250483268101993250484954325049585054585249327177841310671111101161011101164584121112101583211610112011647104116109108131067111110116101110116457610111010311`

Any ideas?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C Lcd(0x27, 16, 6);

#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

char ssid[] = "AESRO2-2.4G";
char password[] = "EA8TDKNFGE";

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

WiFiClient client;

String serverReturn;

String page[]
{
  "Flashlight",
  "Message",
  "S.O.S"
};
void displayPage(int pageNumber)
{
  Lcd.clear();
  Lcd.print(page[pageNumber]);

  Lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  Lcd.print("[Open]");
  Lcd.setCursor(10, 1);
  Lcd.print("[Next]");
}
int currentPage = 0;
int lastPage = 1;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);

  Lcd.begin();

  Lcd.print("BrickOS V5.0.0");
  digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
  delay(300);
  digitalWrite(6, LOW);

  delay(1000);

  if(WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD)
  {
    Lcd.clear();
    Lcd.print("No wifi shield");

    while(true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if(fv != "1.1.0")
  {
    String secline = fv += "->1.1.0"; 
    Lcd.clear();
    Lcd.print("Firmware update");
    Lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    Lcd.print(secline);

    while(true);
  }

  while(status != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Lcd.clear();
    Lcd.print("Connecting to");
    Lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    Lcd.print("network...");

    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    delay(3000);
  }

  Lcd.clear();
  Lcd.print("Connected to:");
  Lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  Lcd.print(ssid);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() 
{
  if(lastPage != currentPage)
  {
    if(currentPage > sizeof(page))
    {
      currentPage = 0;
    }
    displayPage(currentPage);
  }
  lastPage = currentPage;

  serverReturn = "";
  while(client.available()) {
    serverReturn += client.read();
  }
  client.stop();
  if(client.connect("www.nightfall.huskyclick.info", 80)) 
  {
    client.println("GET /msg.php?action=check&ID=1 HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: nightfall.huskyclick.info");
    client.println();
  }
  else
  {
    Lcd.clear();
    Lcd.print("Failed to check");
    Lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    Lcd.print("for messages");
  }

  Serial.println(serverReturn);

  if(serverReturn != "false" && serverReturn != "")
  {
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);

    Lcd.clear();
    Lcd.print("Message received!");

    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);

    delay(1000);

    Lcd.clear();
    Lcd.print(serverReturn);

    delay(5000);
  }

  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what you get when you append an `int` to a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault lies here:

```
while(client.available()) {
  serverReturn += client.read();
}
```

`client.read()` returns an integer. That integer is either the ASCII code of the next character in the buffer, or -1 if there are no characters in the buffer left to read.

You then append that integer to the end of a `String` which gets converted to the ASCII representation of that integer before being appended.

So the string `HTTP`, for instance, which is ASCII characters 72, 84 (twice) and 80 ends up as "72848480".

Instead you need to cast the integer to a char before appending:

```
serverReturn += (char)client.read();
```

Or better still don't use any `String` variables at all and parse the data as it comes in pulling out any information you need to at the time it arrives.